# How to correctly use SecRecord (KeyChain)?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keychain

So I have some code which I originally took from [Xamarin.Auth](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/820c0388beae316e2750de823f2084c5a845de4c/source/Core/Xamarin.Auth.XamarinIOS/AccountStore/KeyChainAccountStore.Aync.cs#L250) to store sensitive data on the device such as password:

```
var record = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
record.Service =  "MyServiceId"
record.Generic = NSData.FromString(value, NSStringEncoding.UTF8); ;
record.Accessible = SecAccessible.WhenUnlocked;

statusCode = SecKeyChain.Add(record);
```

and my guess is that the data stored is encrypted with `SecKind.GenericPassword`. But how is this password being generated and where is this value then being stored. The [Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Security.SecKind/) is very sparse ans just says:

> The SecRecord stores a password.

Who may have access to the `value` I store, is this the correct way to use the `KeyStore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to limit how this record is accessed you can use the `AccessControl` property when you create it instead of just `Accessible`:

```
record.AccessControl = new SecAccessControl(
    SecAccessible.WhenUnlocked,
    SecAccessControlCreateFlags.UserPresence);
```

See: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Security.SecAccessControlCreateFlags/ for more Flags you can apply.

`SecKind` is just the type of record you are storing. Who creates the password doesn't matter, it could be your App, it could be something you get from an API or whatever.

You can also refer to the official Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items

Comment: I have been trying to look into the `UserPresence` flag. What does this flag actually mean?

Comment: "Requires the user to validate, either biometrically or via the device passcode."